# Задача про многослойный перцептрон Ирисы Фишера

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

Вообщем выборка состоит из 150 элементов. Каждый элемент состоит из 4-ех параметров:
`sepal length,sepal width, petal length,petal width.` 
Выборку я перемешал и разбил на 130 элементов обучающей выборки и 20 элементов тестовой.

Чтобы увидеть линейную зависимость я построил 6 графиков:

```
{sepalLength,sepalWidth},
{sepalLength,petalLength},
{sepalLength,petalWidth},
{sepalWidth,petalLength},
{sepalWidth,petalWidth},
{petalLength,petalWidth}
```

Я определил, что для того, чтобы обучить сеть достаточно двух скрытых слоев, так как один класс как минимум во всех графиках я могу отделить. Теперь вопрос сколько нейронов должно быть в скрытых слоях?

В интернете не получилось найти.

**Ниже графики:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я помню теорию, для многослойного перцептрона с `N` скрытыми слоями всегда существует эквивалентный с 1 скрытым слоем (но, возможно, бо́льшим количеством нейронов), поэтому _достаточно_-то будет всегда одного слоя. Что до количества, это вопрос сложный, но, судя по приведенным данным, должно хватить буквально нескольких нейронов (м.б., 4-5).

Answer (score 2):

по идее вам понадобится число нейронов приблизительно равное числу коэффициентов полинома N-го порядка, т.е. [C<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) для модели использующей полином `N`-ой степени.

---

т.к. у вас очень маленькая обучающая выборка (всего 130 элементов), то есть смысл указать больше нейронов, в надежде, что НС найдет более сложные зависимости.

[Вот пример построения удачной НС для решения этой задачи с использованием Keras](https://www.kaggle.com/louisong97/neural-network-approach-to-iris-dataset):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              5000      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 500)               500500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 300)               150300    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 300)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 903       
=================================================================
Total params: 656,703
Trainable params: 656,703
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: а в моем случае сколько? в 1, 2 и 3 слое?